# Detecting application launch event

Tags: ios

I am creating framework and in that framework I want to detect the application launch event and want to perform some operation.

Since, its a framework I cant use applicationDidFinishLaunching: method of UIApplication class.

Is there a way to do this in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On launch there will be a notification posted with the name: `UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification` and when the app becomes active again a notification `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` will be posted.

You can use these notifications to detect the launch of the app you library.

The `UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification` will call just after the app finished loading. So if you implement the [`+ (void)initialize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize) you might be in time to catch it.

If this does not work you will need to either extended the `UIApplication` with a category but this is might cause a lot of hassle.

Comment: Thanks, but for that I will have to first register for these notification and I will miss the very first launch. I want to capture the very first instance when the app will launch.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: I found +(void)load more promising for my use. But marking your answer as correct as it redirected me towards that.

Comment: Great to see you have found a solution and yes may be `+load` is better.